# how do i resolve this problem i seem to have problem with google play services and fire base on android studio native java project

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, onesignal

this is the error i am getting

Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:12.0.1.
> Required by:
> project :app > com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.16.0
> Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement:12.0.1.
> Required by:
> project :app > com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:18.0.0
> Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-api:12.0.1.
> Required by:
> project :app > com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:18.0.0
> Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-sdk:12.0.1.
> Required by:
> project :app > com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:18.0.0
> Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services-stats:12.0.1.
> Required by:
> project :app > com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1 > com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:19.0.0
> Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-iid-interop:12.0.1.
> Required by:
> project :app > com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1 > com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:19.0.0
> Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-measurement-connector:12.0.1.
> Required by:
> project :app > com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1 > com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:19.0.0

Possible solution:

- Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html